# How to manage server id and SQLite id column during syncing?

Tags: android, sqlite, synchronization

I 'm confused about how to manage a server id column and a SQLite database table id column while we sync the data from SQLite to the server or from the server to SQLite in android.

Any one who can explain the syncing process?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try to get the last updated data from server using the sqlite id against db server??@jigar adesara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any one who can explain the syncing process?

SQLite doesn't have any in-built syncing process. You will either have to use an alternative solution or design your own. Noting that a lot very much depends upon the underlying schema and what is being synchronised.

With regard to **id**'s, if used in the intended way, that is to uniquely identify a row, then it's value other than being unique would be insignificant. However, if you use that row for the purpose of storing a value that is of other significance then you may have issues.

### ID purely as a row identifier.

When syncing the **id** column should be ignored in any check for it's existence and the **id** column should not be given a value when inserting/updating/deleting the row to be synchronised. However, this assumes a table where the id is not used to form part of a relationship. If it does form part of a relationship then the other part of the relationship in the other table would have to reflect the assigned **id**.

### ID with other significance

When syncing you would consider the **ID** and you'd provide the **id** when inserting and use it as part of the **WHERE** clause when updating or deleting. Again relationships would need careful consideration.